# jQuery click - prevent multiple clicks in mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, onclick, phonegap-build

I'm using Phonegap for building my iOS/Android app - basically a remote that can emulate a few keys on my laptop's keyboard. (To control video playback etc).

Since its a webpage, I have images that when clicked connects to my Java Socket server on my laptop. The issue I'm facing is, everytime I click a button - just once (like the pause button), I see more than 1 request being fired in the java console. 
But this happens only when I click (touch) in my phone. When I try the same in my laptop's browser, it behaves as expected (just one request).

I went through several posts, where the general advise is to use 'unbind()' and 'off()', but nothing seems to work. The code snippet is below.

```
$("#play").off().on('click',function(){
        //alert("Play");

    jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    async: true,
    url: 'http://'+ip+':10007/function=play?',
    success: function (msg) 
        {  },
    error: function (err)
        { }
    });
});
```

I used that alert to check if the event gets fired more than once. The alert pops up just once, which means, the event is fired just once.
So its just once click (touch) => One event => But multiple requests!

I'm checking the server response with this piece of code:

```
while(true) {                
      Socket sock = servsock.accept();                
      System.out.println("Connection from: " + sock.getInetAddress());                
      Scanner in = new Scanner(sock.getInputStream());                
      PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());                
      String request = "";                
      while (in.hasNext()) {
          request = in.next( );                
          if (request.contains("function="))
          {
            inputLine = request.split("function=")[1];
            System.out.println ("^^^^^" + inputLine); 
            ...
```

The output appears thrice in the console when requested from mobile, but just once when request from my laptop's browser.

I don't understand why and not sure how it can be prevented. 
Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

Another way you can resolve this problem is using a flag that you can set once you click the button. You can then check the value of the flag and return false; in case the value is already set.

// Pseudo Code 
- Keep the flag to false initially. 
- On Click, check the flag value. 
 -- If the flag is set, return false; 
 -- If the flag is not set, set the flag. 
- Once the success method is called, reset the value to false again.

This will resolve the issue of multiple calls at least. Another exercise would be to determine why this is an issue only on a device.

Answer (score 0):

Use `console.log("called")` to check how many times the button is being called. To see the output in chrome is under view->Developer->javaScript console. The `alert("Play");` will only be run once.

Comment: I can try this only in the browser; I tried it only appeared once per click. But from the browser I have verified that the event gets called only once. 
From my phone, this happens more than once.. Hence the alert. I don't know how else to debug in my phone.

Comment: What phone are you using? android or iPhone?

Comment: I'm using an iPhone 6s

Comment: ok you have a few options If you have a mac(not sure if it worked on windows) connect your iPhone to the computer via the cable and in safari go to preferences -> advanced and make sure that show develop menu in  in menu bar is on. Then under develop you will see your phone.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have tried these solutions already but in case you haven't,

1. Try to put `$("#play").off('click');` in the callback function(success or complete) instead of `~off().on('click')~`.
2. Add `return false;` to the callback.

Comment: + If these solutions don't solve the problem, I think the best solution left is using ontouchstart and ontouchend for mobile users only

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar experience with this using jQuery wherein a modal is called twice in one click. Then I realized that the problem is that I invoke events outside my `document.ready` code.

Try these. So instead of having

```
$(function(){
    ...
});

$("#play").off().on('click',function(){
    ...
});
```

Try it this way:

```
$(function(){
    ...

    $("#play").off().on('click',function(){
        ...
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you can fire the click event once is to use [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) instead of [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/). This will make sure the event is fired once. After the AJAX request is complete you can attache the .one() function again.

Your code will look something like:

```
function processOnce() {
    //alert("Play");

    jQuery.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        async : true,
        url : 'http://' + ip + ':10007/function=play?',
        success : function (msg) {
            $("#play").one('click', processOnce());
        },
        error : function (err) {}
    });
}

$("#play").one('click', processOnce());
```

Another possible solution is to wait for deviceready event.
So in your body tag add this:

```
<body onload="onBodyLoad()">
```

and for the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function onBodyLoad() {
      document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
   }

   function onDeviceReady() {
      $(function() {
         // bind your elements
      });
   }
```

Lastly you can add a flag to determine if a click has occurred previously.
So your code will look like this:

```
var clicked = false;

$("#play").on('click', function () {
    if (clicked)
        return;

    clicked = true;
    //alert("Play");

    jQuery.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        async : true,
        url : 'http://' + ip + ':10007/function=play?',
        success : function (msg) {
            clicked = false;
        },
        error : function (err) {}
    });
});
```

I hope this helps.